# Can't find any Directx3D 12 examples

Tags: windows, msdn, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, directx-12

now I want to understand Directx 12 and reading [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn933255(v=vs.85).aspx). It says

> Working samples are installed with the SDK which demonstrate the following:

I found d3d here `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Redist\D3D`
But where are samples for Directx 12?
Thansks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The samples are currently only available to developers on the DX12 Early Access Program and are not currently available despite the documentation making reference to them.

There is one public sample available that I know of [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Direct3D-12-UAP-Sample-ecb1779f). Take a look at Sample3DSceneRenderer.cpp for an example of how to render something using DX12.

Answer (score 6):

Microsoft published a GitHub repository containing several DirectX 12 samples [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples)

Comment: Any luck getting a sample to compile?  It's complaining about unable to find <d3d12.h>.  I can't find the dx12 sdk download anywhere.

Comment: The DirectX SDK moved into the platform SDK a few years ago. For DirectX 12 you'll need the latest [Windows 10 platform SDK](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk).

Comment: Note that by now Microsoft also added the Win10 SDK as an install option to VS2015. Find it under `Windows and Web Development->Universal Windows App Development Tools->Tools and Windows SDK 10.0.xxxx` in the VS installer. You can also install this later on by launching the installer from the `Programs and Features` control panel and chose the `Modify` option.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the official DirectX team samples in the [DirectX-Graphics-Samples GitHub repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples), there are some basic Direct3D 12 samples in the [Xbox-ATG-Samples GitHub repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/Xbox-ATG-Samples/tree/master/Samples/IntroGraphics), a set of game-focused Direct3D 12 enabled Visual Studio templates [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2015/12/17/direct3d-game-visual-studio-templates-redux/), and the [DirectX Tool Kit for DirectX 12 tutorials](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK12/wiki/Getting-Started).

> If you are not already an expert user of Direct3D 11, then you should focus on learning Direct3D 11 before tackling Direct3D 12. DirectX 12 is an API designed for graphics experts and is quite unforgiving to newbies. Generally if you are not already hitting the CPU performance limits of Direct3D 11, you don't need Direct3D 12.